# Reload Facebook app after offloading

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, settings, facebook

I had several apps on my iPhone 5s. When memory got full, I offloaded several of them - Facebook included. When I went to reload Facebook app, it started but did not finish. The logo is stuck in waiting mode.

What should I do to get it to reload fully?

Comment: With the keynote and new product release, the system status page can’t even load for me. https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ You might edit this if you’ve already waited a specific amount of time and restarted the device after an hour or so of waiting.

Comment: https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ loads just fine in Firefox

Comment: You still might not have enough space for the Facebook app.  Last I checked the app was about 400MB.  You probably need to delete more apps and make sure you're running a version of iOS that the app needs.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you're connected to Wi-Fi**

You can only download apps up to 150 MB in size without Wi-Fi. You can also try going on the Internet to check your connection.

> If you’re using cellular data or Wi-Fi and have issues with an app, try to connect to another Wi-Fi network. You can use cellular data for apps up to 150 MB* in size.
>
> To check your Wi-Fi connection, try streaming a video from the Internet to see if it loads quickly. Get help connecting to Wi-Fi or contact your Internet provider for more help.

([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207165))

**Pause and restart the app download**

Try stopping and restarting the download.

See: [How can I cancel an app installation on the iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/how-can-i-cancel-an-app-installation-on-the-iphone/5819#5819)

> 1. Pause the download on the iPhone by tapping the icon.
> 2. Connect the iPhone to iTunes. This will cause iTunes to start downloading the app.
> 3. Go to the Downloads tab in iTunes and delete the download.

You can also restart your device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the volume of the update file. When you open the Appstore, and you can open the details of the update and see the volume. Further you can see. If you have enough free space on your phone. Remove the required number of applications to upgrade.